# if $rst=uvx$ and $r+s+t=u+v+x$ is it necessary for $|r|=|u|$ or $|v|$ or $|x|$?

Tags: number-theory

Given some real numbers $r,s,t,u,v,x$, where $r,s,t,u,v,x $ are non zero. Also,
$$
rst=uvx\,\,\,\text{ and }\,\,\,r+s+t=u+v+x.
$$
Is it true that $|r| =|u|$ or $|v|$ or $|x|$? I can solve for the case of the sum of $2$ numbers. But when i come to $3$ numbers, I am not sure how to prove but I got a feeling that it is true.

Comment: No. Take $r=2,s=4,t=-6,u=1,v=(-1+\sqrt{193})/2,x=(-1-\sqrt{193})/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an example using natural numbers, consider $$(r,s,t)=(1,8,12), (u,v,x)=(2,3,16).$$

Answer (score 0):

Above equation  shown below,

xyz=uvw

(x+y+z)=(u+v+w)

Above simultaneous equation has

parametric solution.

(x,y,z)=((16m+8),(2m+3),(8m-2))

(u,v,w)=((8m+12),(2m+1),(16m-4))

For m=1, (x,y,z)=(5,6,24) & (u,v,w)=(3,12,20)

For m= 2, ( x,y,z)=(7,14,40) & (u,v,w)=(5,28.28)

"OP" does have to worry about negative solution's

because in the above parametrization all solutions

are positive for all positive integers